# C# Polly for handling error http responses

Tags: c#, http, polly

I am trying to implement within a constructor the Polly for handling HTTP error statuses, but I get an error saying:

> The non-generic method cannot be used with type arguments.

I used the code from their website though. Here it is:

```
 public BaseApiManager()
        {
           Retry = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
                        .WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
```

The error is on the second line, at the `OrResult`. I also tried using it with `ApiResponse<T>`, which is my generic class, but it does not work as well.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If I use bool, it does not let me use r.StatusCode

Comment: Looking on documentation: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly your code seems ok. But maybe you have method named HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: No, I use the default one. But it acts like it wants a bool instead.

Comment: I also have above the declaration : private RetryPolicy Retry { get; }

Comment: There was an error in the documentation on the Polly website. It has now been corrected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Polly Retry for the set specific StatusCodes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019007/how-to-set-polly-retry-for-the-set-specific-statuscodes-only)

Answer (score 1):

It should work as follows:

```
Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                    .OrResult(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
                    .WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

The `.OrResult(...)` does not need generic type arguments, because the `.Handle<HttpResponseMessage>(...)` clause has already bound the policy to handle results of type `HttpResponseMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your Retry definition specifing type:

```
private RetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> Retry { get; }
```